# how to stop centered css dropdown menu from twitching (chrome only)

Tags: css, menu, drop-down-menu

I have a css driven dropdown menu, and in Chrome when I hover over the last option the whole thing jumps to the left slightly. I assume it's because the dropdown menu is adding to the overall width of the main list even though it's styled to float. Is there any way to fix this? (it's not doing it in firefox interestingly)

I've noticed by using webdeveloper to outline elements that the last li appears to get wider when it's hovered, but none of the others do.

the applicable sourcecode is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/WsAEW/

Comment: I think it's happening because the content is extending beyond the bottom of the window, thus causing a vertical scroll-bar to appear, thus causing the window size to shrink and the center to be recalculated.

Comment: on the original page there's a veritcal scrollbar all along, so i don't think that's the cause. it is a bit weird though isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked for me changing this:

```
#menu ul li {
    display: inline; 
    position: relative;
}
```

to this:

```
#menu ul li {
    display: inline-block; 
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: that did it! thank you. still not sure why it was doing it in the first place, though.

Comment: I really haven't figured out what happened yet, but solved! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified jsfiddle. I think the issue is fixed. Give it a try.

http://jsfiddle.net/WsAEW/5/

BTW, I only changed the following style. The 'float left' gets the elements to line up horizontally and the 'display: block' gets the top element to size to include the drop down menu.

```
#menu ul li {
    float: left;
    display: block; 
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that makes it so the menu itself is no longer centered.. it's just right to the left of the width of the overall list. I could set the width of the list carefully based on what would center it, but I'd rather be able to edit the contents a bit without having to change the css